Configure NestJS FileFieldsInterceptor Dynamically
A NestJS controller should allow uploading multiple attachment files:
import {
    Controller,
    HttpStatus,
    Param,
    Post,
    Res,
    UploadedFiles,
    UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { FileFieldsInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Controller('invoice')
export class InvoiceController {
    constructor(
        private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    ) {}

    @Post('transform-and-create/:format')
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileFieldsInterceptor([
            {
                name: 'attachment',
                maxCount: 10, // this.configService.get<number>('maxAttachments')
            },
        ]),
    )
    transformAndCreate(
        @Res() response: Response,
        @Param('format') format: string,
        @UploadedFiles()
        files: {
            attachment?: Express.Multer.File[];
        },
    ) {
        response.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        response.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).send('<invoice/>');
    }
}

However, I do not want to hardcode the maximum. number of attachments but configure it dynamically like in the commented code after maxCount above.
How can I achieve this?
